How to Customize the Laravel Activity Log for Specific User Actions?
I'm using the Spatie Laravel Activitylog package to log user actions in my Laravel application. How can I customize the log entries to include additional metadata, such as the IP address or user agent of the user performing the action? Any code examples or best practices would be appreciated.
I tried adding custom properties to the activity log entries by modifying the tapActivity method in the ActivitylogServiceProvider. I expected the additional metadata, like IP address and user agent, to be included in the log entries. However, the custom properties are not being saved, and the log entries remain unchanged.

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-activitylog/v4/introduction ->withProperties(['customProperty' => 'customValue']); for something more complex/automatic, extend the Activity model with your own.

The issue you're facing is likely because the tapActivity method in the ActivitylogServiceProvider isn't the ideal place to modify the logged properties. Here's a better solution to include custom metadata like IP address and user agent in your Spatie Laravel Activitylog entries:
Create a new observer class, for example, ActivityObserver.php. Inside this class, define the creating method:
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class ActivityObserver
{
    public function creating(Model $model)
    {
        if ($model instanceof ActivityLoggable) {
            $model->activity->properties['ip'] = Request::ip();
            $model->activity->properties['user_agent'] = Request::userAgent();
        }
    }
}

In your AppServiceProvider.php (or a custom service provider), register the observer in the boot method:
public function boot()
{
    $models = [YourModel1::class, YourModel2::class, etc.]; // Replace with your models
    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $model::observe(ActivityObserver::class);
    }
}

The models you want to log activity for need to implement the Spatie\Activitylog\Traits\ActivityLoggable trait. This ensures the observer is attached to the model for logging purposes.
